# Let Threads run in a Panel while another Panel is selected and interact with each other and the main window

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have written a file sharing application with sockets. each peer needs a server and a client to interact with other peers. its running as an console application right now and have to be startet manually by passing arguments and so on.. thats not very userfriendly.

so i want to create a GUI interface for that with a main window from where the server can be started, monitored (send some data to a textare like a log window) and while the server is running handle some client-side tasks.

when i decide to choose a cardlayout, is it possible to open a tab where all running server-threads are displayed, start a server thread in it, change the tab but still be able to output dialogs from that tab and each running thread in it even if another card (ex client-threads) is selected?

and otherwise, when i decide to choose different JPanels ex one panel for display all running client-threads to control and monitor them - and one for all server-threads to control and monitor them. is it possible to output thread-actions from a thread running in a JPanel thats not selected?

i hope my explaination is ok and you guys understand what i mean.

Comment: Words typed in all lower case are hard to read, like trying to listen to someone who is mumbling.  Please use an upper case letter at the start of sentences, for the word I, and proper names like `ArrayList` or Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

You can put tabbed Jpanels to each card of a CardLayout and otherwise you can put JPanels on each card in a CardLayout.